# Turning a Piecewise Function into a Single Continuous Expression

Tags: functions, arithmetic, piecewise-continuity

I'm trying to construct a function that contains two parts: one, $g(a,b)$, coming into effect when $a\lt b$, and the other, $h(a,b)$, when $b \lt a$.

The problem is that $a=b$ is a valid possibility which I do not know how to handle, even though

> if $a=b$,  then $g(a,b)=h(a,b)$ and $g'(a,b)=h'(a,b)$.

So there is a real result at $a=b$, but I don't know how to get it out of the equation. there must be a mathematical way to properly express this.

currently I have

f(a,b) = $$\frac{(a-b)-\sqrt{(a-b)^2}}{2(a-b)}g(a,b) + \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)^2}+(a-b)}{2(a-b)}h(a,b).$$
which clearly doesn't cut it, because at $a=b$ the result is some weird specie of infinity.

And I am still working on figuring out $g(a,b)$ and $h(a,b)$, so I can't provide you with an example at this point.

So to recap: How do you join parts of functions into one continuous arithmetic function? (without input logic)

"you can'd do that" is a valid answer, but I'd like to know why.

Comment: And you don't want to use a piecewise function? You want just a single expression? What kind of functions are you allowed to use? Any problem with $\max$ and $\min$?

Comment: You are essentially looking for a formula such so that $$i(a,b)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 &\text{if }a\leq b\\0&\text{if }a\gt b\end{array}\right.$$Then you can define your function as $i(a,b)g(a,b) + (1-i(a,b))h(a,b)$. But $i$ will not be continuous.

Comment: @arturo (sqrt(pow((a-b),2))+(a-b))/(2*(a-b)) basically is a is greater b, but the inverse, or 1 - that isn't a greater than or equal b. but yes, i would be looking for something like that.

and I mean I can use conditional statements, but i would 'like' a form that is universally portable, something you 'could' punch into a calculator, something that you could just copy from c++ and paste into haskell or calc.exe. I know plenty of ways to do it, but I'm asking the crowd for a universal solution, should one exist. If anyone (heh), you would know.

Comment: @arturo in short, yea.

Comment: also, what do you call these functional condition elements? (for googling)

Comment: Functions defined that way are called "piecewise defined functions" (or "piece-wise")

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41444 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58792.

Comment: so i have to accept the consensus that a discontinuity cannot be plugged. :(

Comment: BTW: what @Arturo was doing in his second comment is in fact an instance of the so-called Iverson bracket, but in slightly different notation. Raymond, in his answer, tells you how you can express your Iverson bracket in terms of the unit step or sign functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) defined this way (other variants for $H(0)$ exist) :

$$
H(x)=\begin{cases}
x<0&\ 0\\[8pt]
x=0&\frac 12\\[8pt]
x>0&\ 1\\[8pt]
\end{cases}
$$

(you may too write $H$ as a [$\rm{sign}$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) : $\ H(x)=\dfrac {1+\rm{sign}(x)}2$) then :

$$\boxed{\displaystyle f(a,b)= g(a,b)\cdot H(b-a)+ h(a,b)\cdot H(a-b)}$$

(with value $\dfrac{g(a,a)+h(a,a)}2$ for $a=b$ of course)

To get a 'smoothed' result you may replace $H$ by a [Sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) :
$\ \displaystyle S(x)=\frac 1{1+e^{-x}}\ $ or other [variants](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Gjl-t%28x%29.svg).

Since $\ H(x)=\lim_{n->\infty} S(n\cdot x)\ $ you may replace $H(x)$ by something like $S(n\cdot x)$ with any $n \gg 1$ to get a smooth transition!

Let's illustrate this with an example : $x\mapsto x^2$ for negative $x$ and $x\mapsto \cos(10 x)$ for positive $x$ illustrated with $n=1000$ and $n=100$ :

```
f(t)=t^2/(1+exp(1000*t))+cos(10*t)/(1+exp(-1000*t)
```

[image: n=1000]

```
f(t)=t^2/(1+exp(100*t))+cos(10*t)/(1+exp(-100*t)
```

[image: n=100]

Hoping it helped,

Comment: that's pretty darn badass dude. it's not perfect but i can adapt.  many thanks.

Comment: @user35945: glad it helped! One of the possible problems is exponential overflow or underflow (i.e. the resulting function should be tested for the minimal an maximal value allowed).

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable for you to write
$$g(a,b)=u\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+(b-a)\cdot g_*(a,b)\\
h(a,b)=u\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+(b-a)\cdot h_*(a,b)$$
then you can write
$$f(a,b)=u\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+\frac{(b-a)-|b-a|}{2}\cdot g_*(a,b)+\frac{(b-a)+|b-a|}{2}\cdot h_*(a,b)$$

---

On the other hand, if you have to consider $g,h$ as opaque functions, it is impossible to find continuous $\varphi,\psi$ such that
$$f(a,b)=\varphi(a,b)g(a,b)+\psi(a,b)h(a,b)$$
(this is because necessarily $\varphi(a,b)=1$ when $a<b$ and $0$ when $a>b$, creating a discontinuity).

In particular, if $\varphi,\psi$ are constructed from constants, the variables $a,b$, operators like $+,-,\times,/$ and continuous functions like $\exp,\log,\sin,\cos,\tan,\sqrt{\cdot},|\cdot|$ (paying attention to their domain of definition), then they are necessarily continuous.