# How to merge two (or more) continuous functions into one?

Tags: functions, cubics

I have two functions,

> $g(x) = 4x^3$, domain $0<x<0.5$
>
> $h(x) = \frac{1}{2}((2x-1)^3+1)$, domain $0.5\le x<1$

which I derived from:

> $g(x) = ((2x)^3)/2$, domain $0<x<0.5$
>
> $h(x) = ((2(x-0.5))^3)/2+0.5$, domain $0.5\le x<1$

I want to combine g(x) and h(x) info one function, f(x). If it helps, h(x) is derived from g(x). Here is a [graph of g(x) and h(x)](http://fooplot.com/plot/ay95ja51it). h(x) is g(x), [reflected] or [rotated $\pi$ radians] about $(0.5, 0.5)$.

I have looked at other questions related, such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174483/turning-a-piecewise-function-into-a-single-continuous-expression), but I wasn't sure how to apply the solution to this scenario because my functions didn't have two parameter. How can I combine these two into one function f?

> $f(x)=?$

Comment: @Dave: How about $f(x) = 4x^3(u_0(x) - u_\frac{1}{2} (x)) + \dfrac{1}{2} ((2x -1 )^3+1)u_1(x)$. Plot this and your piecewise one and see what you get.

Comment: The definition of $h(x)$ in your post does not match the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Both are cubic functions:

One thing you may try is $$f(x) = Ag(x) + Bh(x)$$

Evaluate f(x) in those interval ends and get the value of A and B.  I have not tried but should work.

Comment: If $A, B$ are constants $f(x)$ is still analytic.